# What does SGBD mean?

Tags: database, abbreviation

As I could not find the answer anywhere else:

What is SGBD? Is it "Système de Gestion de Bases de
Données" (Database management system)?

E.g. it is used in responses to these
two Stack Overflow questions:

1. [Trip time calculation in relational databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83050)
2. [How can I use Python for large scale development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236407)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes you're right, I confirm that in French we use the abbreviation SGBD for 'Système Gestion de Base de Données' (DataBase Management System / DBMS) to which we can sometimes add R (SGBDR) 'Système Gestion de Base de Données *Relationnelle*' (RDBMS).

Comment: We also use it in Portuguese ("sistema de gerenciamento de banco de dados")

Answer (score 2):

SGBD also applies for Spanish: *Sistema de Gestion de Bases de Datos*.

Answer (score 2):

SGBD might also mean "Sistema de Gestão de Banco de Dados" in Portuguese. Literally, "Database Management System", our good old DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

A SGBD is a "Système de Gestion de Base de Données" which is exactly the same as a DBMS. I can't say much more since there are no great translation subtlety.

Answer (score 0):

SGBD = Database System

The english acronym is RDBMS (Relational database management system)

Comment: If we do not always put the R is because not all DataBase are only relational ^^